# Estimating density function at a single point

Tags: probability, density-function, estimation

> Let $f(x)$ be a continuous probability density function (PDF).
> What is the best method to estimate $f(a)$ for a given single point $a\in\mathbb{R}$ given i.i.d samples of the PDF (i.e. $x_i \sim f(x), i=1,\cdots, n$)?

Should I estimate the entire density,  for example using kernel density estimation, to find an estimator at a single point $f(a)$?

Is it possible to perform the estimation without estimating the entire PDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you imply that you do not have an analytical expression of your PDF? If you only have the data points $x_i$ then I can only see that you have to somehow estimate the PDF from those and then evaluate this estimation at $\alpha$. As you said using kernel density estimation is a way to solve your problem, though different smoothing kernels can be used.
I would also suggest reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation#Definition)  (most probably you have already done so)

Comment: Thank you for answering. I don't have an analytical expression. But I was thinking that since I want to extract less information form the data than the entire distribution, it might be possible to perform the estimation without estimating the entire PDF.